# How to shift elements in an RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Scala and try to figure out how to shift elements in an RDD.
I read the pairs from a CSV file:

```
var listOfPairs = Spark.sc.textFile( <filePath> )
                  .map(aLine => aLine.split(","))
                  .map(aPair=> (aPair(0), aPair(1)))
```

The content of the file is as follows:

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
e,5
```

In every loop, I want to shift the elements once.

```
for (i <- 1 to numberOfLoops) { ...?... }
```

Each step will look like this, for numberOfLoops=3:

```
[(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),(d,4),(e,5)]  
1: [ (b,2), (c,3), (d,4), (e,5), (a,1) ]  
2: [ (c,3), (d,4), (e,5), (a,1), (b,2) ]  
3: [ (d,4), (e,5), (a,1), (b,2), (c,3) ]
```

Comment: **RDDs** are distributed collections, this kind of operations are too difficult to perform and will be very inefficient. Can you share why floor you want to do this?

Comment: I am asked to use RDDs, is it possible to do it? If not, maybe I can use 2D arrays.

Comment: Everything is possible, but as I said this one will be difficult and inefficient. If you think an array is a suitable replacement then either you do not need or do not understand **RDDs**. These are distributed collections, that are designed to hold millions of records, which weight terabytes of ram. And they allow that by distributing its contents across many machines. Anyways, that is why I asked why you need this, because there may be other way. You said you were asked to do that using **RDDs**, is this a homework? _(if so it is a strange one but maybe that want to make the contrast)_

Comment: Well, the file has more records, I just put few lines. And yes, it is an homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic idea of how to perform a shift.
This can be improved for performance *(specially there is a way to avoid multiple iterations for many consecutive shifts)*, but that is left as an exercise for the reader.

The basis of the algorithm is to give each element an unique key, then create a copy of the data with its key shifted, and the join them by key.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
import spark.implicits._

val data = sc.parallelize(List("a,1", "b,2", "c,3", "d,4", "e,5"))
val listOfPairs = data.map(_.split(",")).map { case Array(a, b) => a -> b }

val indexed = listOfPairs.zipWithIndex.map { case (tuple, idx) => idx -> tuple }
val lastIndex = indexed.count() - 1

val newIndexed = indexed.map {
  case (idx, (a, b)) =>
    if (idx == lastIndex)
      (0L, (a, b))
    else
      (idx + 1, (a, b))
}

val shifted = newIndexed.join(indexed).map {
  case (_, ((a, _), (_, b))) => a -> b
}
```